# iOS non-renewing subscription multiple device support

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am implementing non-renewing subscription for iOS devices.
Apple guidelines say IAP's should be available to all user devices:

> You must make your In-App Purchase items available to all of the devices registered to a user.

I am implementing a user/password system for my users to enable restoring their purchases on other devices, but the question is - How many devices should I support? 
If I don't set a limit, people can take advantage on it.

According to Apple, a user can register up to 10 devices with an Apple ID (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4627), but that includes also computers. Would it be safe to say 5 devices is the limit?

Comment: That's also my plan (5 device restore limit) for my app (yet to undergo review).